# How to find the unit vector in a rhombus as a function of a unit vector?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

The figure from below shows a set of vectors. Find the unit vector of $\vec{A}+\vec{B}$ as a function of the unit vectors $\vec{u_1}$ and $\vec{u_2}$. It is known that the sides of the rhombus is $6$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\frac{(3\vec{u_1}+\vec{u_2})}{\sqrt{10}}\\
2.&\frac{(3\vec{u_1}+\vec{u_2})}{\sqrt{13}}\\
3.&\frac{(3\vec{u_1}-\vec{u_2})}{\sqrt{10}}\\
4.&\frac{(3\vec{u_1}-\vec{u_2})}{\sqrt{7}}\\
5.&\frac{(3\vec{u_1}-\vec{u_2})}{\sqrt{13}}\\
\end{array}$

I'm totally lost at this problem exactly how to find the resultant. The information regarding the sides of the rhombus it is a little bit ambiguous to me as it is stated. Does it mean that the sum of all sides is $6$ or each side is $6$?. How should I made the interpretation?. Because if it is meant $4x=6$ then $x=\frac{3}{2}$. But if it meant that each side is $6$. then $\left\|\vec{B}\right\|=6$ and $\left\|\vec{A}\right\|=3$.

Can somebody help me here?.

Comment: Something is clearly wrong as when you transpose $\vec a$ downwards along the diagonal, you get $\vec a +\vec b=6\vec u_2$

Comment: Are you going to post your entire homework set here, showing no effort or work or context....?  That's not what this site is for.